# When Creating Tool, Edit Page will load Blank [system-frontier]

Tags: mysql, iis

I just Start using System Frontier, The installation was a little complicated with a couple of errors but it was completed and the page is loading I completed the Post-installation steps.

Now the Issue:
When I go to tools create tool load the information and script, The Edit Page that should load after that is not loading is just a Blank Page.

What I try:

1. I check Data base information: I don't have a basic knowledge of MySQL but so far I see no errors.
2. I tried to restart the IIS Server and services.
3. I tried to load the Page in Different browsers and Run as incognito still the page will not load.

Conclusion:
If anyone has tried the tools and presented with this error and might have a solution please let me know Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm not a native English speaker so if there was any typos or error sorry about that I hope it was understandable.

Answer (score 2):

After reading a little more I found the issue and there is an option that should have been activated for the issue to be a result or I will say to activate the option.

Answers:
Add an entry for your management server. (Settings > Management Servers)

Sorry, I hope I did not waste anyone's time.